# Downcasting error in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Am getting an error in the configureCheckmarkForCell method, which returns an "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error"

It does not return an error for configureTextForCell method though. Why?

Here are the methods:

```
func configureCheckmarkForCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withChecklistItem item: ChecklistItem) {

        let label = cell.viewWithTag(1001) as! UILabel //Getting error message on this line

            if item.checked {
                label.text = "√"
            } else {
                label.text = ""
            }
    }

    func configureTextForCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withChecklistItem item: ChecklistItem) {

        let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
        label.text = item.text
    }
```

Comment: You retrieve views with different tags (1000 vs. 1001). So probably one is an UILabel and the other one is nil.

Comment: I'd say that it's not the downcasting that fails, but rather the `viewWithTag:` method, which would mean that there: either is no view with the specified tag (check if everything is correct in IB); or the view is not created at that point.